Error al crear un registro en una tabla con clave foránea
Tengo estas dos tablas en mi base de datos mysql:
CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `supplier` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
CREATE TABLE `purchase_details` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `purchase_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

Y creo las claves primarias, las autoincrementales y las claves ajenas:
ALTER TABLE `purchases`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `supplier` (`supplier`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `purchase_id` (`purchase_id`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `purchases`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `purchase_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`purchase_id`) REFERENCES `purchases` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `purchase_details_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Para probarlos primero creé un registro en compras, porque ese total almacena la suma de totales de los registros en detalles_compra que tienen el _id de compra de la tabla de compras.
Además en el formulario de detalles_compra aparece el id_compra al que se tiene que asociar, en un input readonly.
Luego, intento crear un registro en detalles_compra con el ID de compra que creé anteriormente y me da este error:

Error grave: mysqli_sql_exception no detectado: no se puede agregar ni
actualizar una fila secundaria: falla una restricción de clave externa

He leído en internet que primero hay que crear el registro de la tabla secundaria y luego el primario, pero yo tengo que hacerlo al revés.

No, no se puede al reves como lo describis vos... Si, se puede hacer tranquilamente en el orden que quieras, si sacas todas las restricciones de la db y lo haces todo a mano por negocio. si la db solo maneja indices y llaves primarias, vos podes hacer lo que quieras con el resto, sin preocuparte por lo que hace la db, y sin que la misma se ocupe de eso...

Entonces, me dices que una solución podría ser quitar las claves ajenas e introducir yo el id de compra en cada detalle de compra, en mi propio formulario?

Eso es lo que hago yo en absolutamente todos mis sistemas.. pero queda a gusto de cada uno... y no lo hagas en el front.. todo se hace en el back, siempre... si le sacas control a la DB de esas cosas, tenes mas facilidad para controlar otras cosas en el front.. por ejemplo, esto que queres hacer...

Ok gracias, voy a intentarlo. Por cierto, tendrá algo que ver que el cotejamiento de algunas tablas sea diferente?, todas son utf8, pero unas spanish y otras general.

No tiene por qué no funcionar. ¿Cuál es la definición de tu tabla de productos? ¿Cuál es el INSERT que genera el error descrito en la pregunta? En cuanto al CHARSET y al COLLATE, siendo que son tablas relacionadas, conviene que tengan la misma definición también en ese sentido. Aunque puedas hacerlo sin delegar en la base de datos, como sugiere @gbianchi, nada te impide contar con ella para lograr esto, de hecho, las bases de datos existen también para ello y, a no ser una causa justificada, no deberías pasar por alto un diseño coherente partiendo de la misma BD.

@A.Cedano en este caso, por lo que entendi, queria generar un detalle sin tener cabecera.. lo cual puede ser algo comun... y si pones un constrain, no te deja, pero si lo tenes perfectamente controlado por tu sistema, es correcto.. porque en realidad, esa restriccion de la db, no siempre es real en el negocio...

@gbianchi ya, pero desde mi punto de vista, querer generar el detalle de una compra que no existe es reflejo de que hay un error en la lógica del programa. De ser así, lo más grave es ese error de lógica, el cual debes afrontar y corregir, resolviendo así el problema en la raíz. Un error en la lógica del programa te puede llevar a soluciones rocambolescas, hasta encontrarte muchas veces en un callejón sin salida.

No es un error eh.. muchas veces se pueden generar detalles de facturas no generadas, tipo carrito.. pero son puntos de vista y tienen que ver con los negocios... ;) @A.Cedano

@gbianchi ya, pero sigue siendo un error, en la lógica, o incluso en el diseño, porque un carrito de compra no es una compra. No tengo demasiada experiencia en este tipo de programas, pero, apelando a la lógica, que no es otra cosa que aplicar el sentido común, tú no puedes registrar una compra hasta que la misma no se realiza como tal y esto ocurre cuando el cliente ha efectuado el pago de los productos. Quizá en este caso el error esté ahí precisamente, en llamar compra a algo que no es tal.

Puede ser.. podrias generar una orden de venta sin facturar en la misma tabla de la factura.. tambien podria estar en otra.. ya ahi, es meterse en cada negocio... el punto es que no necesariamente tenes que meter todas las reglas en la db, por mas que sean reglas, porque tal vez por negocio no lo sean...

@gbianchi yo no me refiero a reflejar a cualquier precio las reglas de negocio en la base de datos, sino a diseñar un modelo de datos coherente lo más posible. En particular yo evitaría privar a la BD de gestionar cosas que le son propias, como son la integridad referencial o las claves foráneas. Sea como sea, en esta pregunta falta contexto. Por ejemplo, ¿cuál es la estructura de la tabla products? ¿Cuál es la consulta que produce el error referido en la pregunta? Creando las tablas adecuadamente, no ocurre error ninguno.

Yo no  veo ningún problema en este diseño, sólo tienes que crear correctamente las tablas y garantizar que las cosas existan antes de usarlas, lo contrario no tendría sentido. Es decir, no puedes intentar usar una compra fantasma o un producto fantasma.
Lo que describes al decir:

Luego, intento crear un registro en detalles_compra con el ID de
compra que creé anteriormente y me da este error:
Error grave: mysqli_sql_exception no detectado: no se puede agregar ni
actualizar una fila secundaria: falla una restricción de clave externa

Podría ocurrir si intentas una compra que no existe, o un producto que no existe.
Luego esto:

He leído en internet que primero hay que crear el registro de la tabla
secundaria y luego el primario, pero yo tengo que hacerlo al revés.

No queda claro a qué te refieres. ¿Qué es lo que tienes que hacer al revés exactamente y por qué crees que tienes que hacerlo así? Pregunto esto, porque sospecho que aquí hay riesgo de sacrificar un modelo de datos sólido debido a alguna incomprensión o error en el planteamiento del problema y/o de la solución a un problema dado.
Veamos un ejemplo completo, el cual no da error ninguno. He incluido la creación de la tabla products, que es fundamental para entender el problema y los INSERT que podrían dar error:
CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `supplier` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;


CREATE TABLE `purchase_details` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `purchase_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `purchases`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `supplier` (`supplier`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `purchase_id` (`purchase_id`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `purchases`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `purchase_details`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `purchase_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`purchase_id`) REFERENCES `purchases` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `purchase_details_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO `purchases` VALUES (1,20240503,1,100);

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (1,'P1');

INSERT INTO  `purchase_details` VALUES (1,1,1,2,50,100,20240503);

SELECT * FROM `purchases`;




id
date
supplier
total




1
2024-05-03
1
100.00



SELECT * FROM `purchase_details`;




id
purchase_id
product_id
qty
price
total
date




1
1
1
2
50.00
100.00
2024-05-03



fiddle
Finalmente, podrías prescindir de esas columnas total, realmente son campos calculados que se obtienen mediante la cantidad de productos y el precio del producto. A no ser que haya otras realidades, como descuentos de temporada o cosas así y aunque sea de ese modo, eso de podría gestionar desde otra tabla que controle dichos descuentos, los productos que entran en esa política de descuentos según la fecha, el porcentaje aplicado, etc.

Muchas gracias a los dos. Al final, eliminé la clave ajena y funciona bien, aunque necesite iindicar qué compra quiero utilizar al realizar un detalle de compra. @A.Cedano Cuando una cajera de supermercado comienza a cobrat tu compra primero abre un nuevo proceso de compra y después comienza a ingresar los productos que compras. Yo, por lo menos, lo entendí así.

@CharlyUtrilla es correcto lo que dices en tu comentario, sin embargo, para el caso que expones, esto no tiene por que ser así: He leído en internet que primero hay que crear el registro de la tabla secundaria y luego el primario, pero yo tengo que hacerlo al revés. No tienes que hacer nada al revés. La compra ocurre a partir de cosas que ya existen: productos por un lado y un carrito de la compra o como se llame, por otro. El error, tal y como lo dice el mensaje, ocurría porque estabas intentando agregar en alguna parte algo que no existía.
